# Base64 html email received as plain text

Tags: php, email, smtp, base64

I am building an html to send over smtp with spoon-library.com but I receive the mail as plain text and not an html e-mail:

Gist of received e-mail: https://gist.github.com/freshface/e34193f7ea3e25eea12e7131f4f94733

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use "setHTMLContent" method like it shown [here](http://spoon-library.be/tutorials/email/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

setHTMLContent didn't fix it.
The bug seems to be in Spoon itself, i upgraded the swift mailer.